# Unable to get a Window, abort for kivy

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, kivy

This is the error:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7SCc.png

I have already seen and followed all answers in this site. But I am facing same problem

Comment: did you created a virtual environment for the project

Comment: No, I didn't created any virtual environment. Is it must? How can I do that? please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is highly recommended to use virtual environment for kivy

1. Setup terminal and pip

> python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools virtualenv

2. Create a virtual environment inside the root directory of your project

> python -m virtualenv kivy_venv

> kivy_venv\Scripts\activate

> source kivy_venv/Scripts/activate

After creating virtual env then install kivy on virtual env

For more details - https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html#install-pip